# How to return Entry<K, V> from method

Tags: java

I have a method and I want to return an Entry object from this method. Since Entry is an interface I can't return a new Entry. Is there any other way?

```
public Entry<String, byte[]> getSomeEntry(){


 String = ....;
 byte[] = ....;

 //here I want to return an Entry object

 }
```

Comment: If it is an interface then you need to return an instance of an object that implements the interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instantiate [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) class, which implements the `Map.Entry` interface:

```
String key;
byte[] value;

Entry<String, byte[]> entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, byte[]>(key, value);
```

Oh, and there is also an [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) if you need it.